# Hacer un insert en mysql si el valor a insertar es igual a un valor predefinido

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hola a todos espero me puedan ayudar necesito hacer un insert en una tabla de mysql
que solo me inserte cuando un valor es igual a salida 
el ejemplo seria asi

```
INSERT INTO `inventario`
( `movimiento`,
  `noserie`, 
  `producto`, 
  `origen`, 
  `destino`, 
  `categoria_d`, 
  `categoria_o`, 
  `concepto`,
  `observaciones`)

  VALUES 

  ('Salida',
   '2',
   'ejemplo1', 'ejemplo1','ejemplo1','ejemplo1', 'ejemplo1',
    'ejemplo1','ejemplo1',
    'ejemplo1'), //// si el primer valor es igual a salida me los inserte

    ('Entrada','3','ejemplo1','ejemplo1','ejemplo1','ejemplo1','ejemplo1',
    'ejemplo1','ejemplo1','ejemplo1') 
    //// si el primer valor es diferente a 'salida' no me los inserte
```

lo que no se es como iniciar la comparacion para insertarlos espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: [mysql-insert-if-condition-is-true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017313/mysql-insert-if-condition-is-true)

Comment: no se desde donde disparas esta query, pero no es mucho mas facil que el sistema que arma esta query y pasa los valores, directamente no haga la consulta si no se cumplen las condiciones?

Comment: gbianchi hice lo que me dijiste fue mas facil muchas gracias :D